# Precision and recall for which class is calculated in GridSearchCV?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, precision, xgboost, gridsearchcv

I'm running GridSearchCV on XGBoost model to tune some parameters. My target variable is binary. When I use, 'recall' or 'precision' as scoring metrics in cross validation, I get a single value. I'm not using make_scorer, I'm only passing strings for whichever metric I want to calculate. I'm confused if the recall and precision is for class '0' or class '1'.

So, which precision and recall is for which class?

As you can see in the example image below (not related to my model) from sklearn's classification_report module, both precision and recall can be calculated for individual labels/classes in the target variable.
[image]

Comment: I think that during cross validation, `sklearn` reports a single averaged metric over all classes, which reflects how well the estimator did for that *fold* rather than being a class-specific value. `classification_report` gives you the break down for each class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it's calculated for the second class (`classes_[1]`). Many utilities and metrics in scikit-learn accept a `pos_label` which you can use to control which class is assumed to be the positive class.

For instance, `precision_score` has a `pos_label` which controls this: [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html)

Another example is in `PrecisionRecallDisplay` which you can see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.PrecisionRecallDisplay.html#sklearn.metrics.PrecisionRecallDisplay.from_estimator).

[image]

Comment: Yes, I managed to do that. Like this as a custom scorer, since I did not understand the default output                                                                                  
 scorer = {'recall':make_scorer(recall_score, pos_label=1),
              'precision': make_scorer(precision_score, pos_label=1),
              'f1Macro':'f1_macro',
              'f1Micro':'f1_micro',
              'accuracy': 'accuracy'}
I just wanted to clarify what's the default output we get.